# How can I change the default keyboard layout in Ubuntu 10.10?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, keyboard-layout

Ubuntu keeps detecting my keyboard layout as Romanian. It almost always does this on a reboot and some times on waking from sleep. Some times it just randomly changes back to Romanian while the computer is on. I always set it back to "USA" in the keyboard preferences and delete the Romanian layout. What files configure this in Ubuntu? I looked in xorg.conf and did not find any keyboard settings. How can I set this to USA permanently?

I have a laptop with a typical US layout built in keyboard and I also have an apple keyboard that is also US layout connected via USB. I have run other distributions on this same setup before and never had this happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the graphical Desktop you may choose System->Preferences->Keyboard and select your layout there.

Using the terminal `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-data` should do the trick.